# jquery callback anonymous function closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, anonymous-function

I've declared the variable `elem` in both of the loops below; however, when the anonymous function in the first loop gets called (after the 400ms `fadeOut` effect is finished) the `elem` seems to refer to the value of `elem` which was assigned in the second loop.  In other words, the code works correctly if you rename `elem` in the second loop to any other variable name.

Is there a way to make a closure around the anonymous function so that the value of `elem` is not changed in the context of the anonymous function?

```
for (var i = 0; i < outs.length; i++) {
  var elem = this.elementAtPoint(outs[i]);

  $(elem).fadeOut(400, function () {
    $(elem).removeClass("white black queen"); //UPDATE
    $(elem).show();
  });
  //$(elem).css("background", "red");
}

for (var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {
  var elem = this.elementAtPoint(ins[i]);
  var piece = this.board.pieceAt(ins[i]);

  $(elem).hide();

  $(elem).addClass(this.classForPiece(piece));

  $(elem).fadeIn(400);
}
```

Comment: There is no block scope in javascript, only functions defines scope

Comment: What's `out`? You can loop arrays and objects with jQuery's `$.each` which creates a new scope.

Comment: You can learn more about `JavaScript Hoisting`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a anonymous self executing function

```
for (var i = 0; i < outs.length; i++) {
    (function(elem){
        $(elem).fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(elem).removeClass("white black queen"); //UPDATE
            $(elem).show();
        });
        //$(elem).css("background", "red");
    })(this.elementAtPoint(outs[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, variable scope is decided by function, so you can wrap the two for loops in two function. a wrapper function example:

```
(function(){
    //put you for loop here
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid creating lots of closures inside loops, they would be inefficient as they create copies of the current scope. Instead I'd simply create a couple of extra functions then call them inside your loops:

```
var fadeInPiece = function(elem, piece){
  $(elem).hide();
  $(elem).addClass(this.classForPiece(piece));
  $(elem).fadeIn(400);
}

var fadeOutElem = function(elem){
  $(elem).fadeOut(400, function () {
    $(elem).removeClass("white black queen"); //UPDATE
    $(elem).show();
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < outs.length; i++)
  fadeOutElement(this.elementAtPoint(outs[i]));

for (var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++)
  fadeInPiece(this.elementAtPoint(ins[i]), this.board.pieceAt(ins[i]));
```